# why chrome finish a keep-alive connection after there is no data exchange after a while

Tags: tcp, webserver, nio, keep-alive

I'm using java's nio to test the keep-alive connection, just wondering if I don't close the connection at the server side, what will happen, I thought the connection will keep util server side close the connection,but i was wrong, after a while for no data exchange, next chrome request will finish the connection and start a new connection, why?

below figure was captured on wireshark
[wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K19zH.png)

below figure was captured on wireshark (not too long between two request)
[wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpAwM.png)

here's my code

```
public static void nioStart() throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel socketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8000));
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(Boolean.FALSE);

        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        while (true) {
            selector.select();
            Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            for (SelectionKey key : selectedKeys) {
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                    SocketChannel clientChannel = serverChannel.accept();
                    clientChannel.configureBlocking(Boolean.FALSE);
                    clientChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    SocketChannel clientChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    System.out.println("hashCode = " + clientChannel.hashCode() + ", remoteAddress = " + clientChannel.getRemoteAddress());
                    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                    int read;
                    while ((read = clientChannel.read(byteBuffer)) > 0) {
                        byteBuffer.flip();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
                        byteBuffer.get(bytes);
                        byteBuffer.clear();
                    }
                    // When SocketChannel.read() returns -1, it typically indicates that the remote end of the channel has been closed gracefully. This is the usual behavior when reading from a SocketChannel in non-blocking mode
                    if (read == -1) {
                        System.out.println("close client connection");
                        clientChannel.close();
                        continue;
                    }
                    String response = "hello, client!";
                    byteBuffer.put(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: " + response.getBytes().length + "\r\n\r\n" + response).getBytes());
                    byteBuffer.flip();
                    clientChannel.write(byteBuffer);
                }
            }
            selectedKeys.clear();
        }

    }
```

if anyone know the reason why, please answer, thanks a lot

I thought server side will make the close firt

Comment: Chrome’s connection pool has expired the connection. Nothing to do with NIO.